# Making a physics body so that another body passes through

Tags: box2d

Basically I "think" I want a static body that does not have any density so another body can "pass through it" without getting slowed down. I tried this and it doesn't seem to work. What would be the proper way to do this?

Any version (C,C++, Java) would be fine for an answer.

Comment: Why make it a Box2D body at all if you don't want it to interact with other bodies? Or is there just *one* specific body you want to be able to pass through this body?

Comment: Why don't you just use collision groups?

Comment: +Byte46 I was making it a body because I am going to try to use it as the boundaries for a cellular automate (?) based of the location of the body (think body has sub bodies) also it helped with debug rendering. I could remove it as a body but that isn't the question I asked.

Comment: Use sensors, instead of body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A collision filter is probably what you are looking for, since Box2D makes all objects collide by default.

Take a look at this tutorial: http://blog.allanbishop.com/box-2d-2-1a-tutorial-part-5-collision-filtering/

Comment: the link is not working.....